# how to join Query for particular customer group and custom customer_entity_varchar attribute?

Tags: attributes, collection, join-table

Here in my collection -> Table structure is :

```
1,id,                mydb,table_name,INT UNSIGNED,,10,3,0
2,userid,            mydb,table_name,INT UNSIGNED,,10,5,0
3,transctionid,      mydb,table_name,TEXT,,65535,15,0
4,requesttime,       mydb,table_name,TIMESTAMP,,19,19,0
5,creditamount,      mydb,table_name,SMALLINT,,5,4,0
6,creditedtime,      mydb,table_name,TIMESTAMP,,19,19,0
7,status,            mydb,table_name,SMALLINT UNSIGNED,,5,1,0
```

`other_is_dummy_cm` =  is customer attribute.

In This collection I need only customer group id = 9 and other_is_dummy_cm = 0  should be in table else not

So my collection is :

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('user/transaction')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq' => 3));
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array(
    'account'=> 'campusm_account'),
    'account.userid = main_table.userid',
    array('account.accountno', 'account.ifsc', 'account.bankaddress', 'account.bankname','account.pancard_no.')
);

$firstnameAttr = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('1', 'firstname');
$lastnameAttr = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('1', 'lastname');
// trying to put but getting error.
$dummyAttr = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('1', 'other_is_dummy_cm');

$collection->getSelect()
    ->join(array(
        'ce1' => 'customer_entity_varchar'),
        'ce1.entity_id=main_table.userid', array('firstname' => 'value')
    )
    ->where('ce1.attribute_id='.$firstnameAttr->getAttributeId()) // Attribute code for firstname.
    ->join(array(
        'ce2' => 'customer_entity_varchar'),
        'ce2.entity_id=main_table.userid', array('lastname' => 'value')
    )
    ->where('ce2.attribute_id='.$lastnameAttr->getAttributeId()) // Attribute code for lastname.
    ->columns(new Zend_Db_Expr("CONCAT(`ce1`.`value`, ' ',`ce2`.`value`) AS fullname"));
```